# List occupied cells across multiple cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have 4 variables and wish to list which (maximum of 3) variables are being used.
I have used VBA functions before but I am stumped as to the reason this isn't working..

The four variables are percentages so for example:

if (20%,empty,20%,60%) I want the three cells to be (A,C,D)

if (50%,50%,empty,empty) => (A,B,empty)

Hello,

if (empty,empty,100%,empty) => (C,empty,empty)

The code I have at the moment isn't working (for the first cell):

```
Function whichtoa(w As Integer, x As Integer, y As Integer, z As Integer) As String

If w <> 0 Then
  whichtoa = "A"
ElseIf x <> 0 Then
  whichtoa = "B"
ElseIf y <> 0 Then
  whichtoa = "C"
ElseIf z <> 0 Then
  whichtoa = "D"
End If

End Function
```

Could it be to do with the empty cells being general and the others being a percentage? I can't really change this as the data is coming from another program. 
Could I use a null check or something similar?

Thanks in advance!

Lucas

Comment: From the looks of it if `W <> 0` then it would just return `A`. If statements will only process for one condition and cease the block if a condition is met

Comment: `IsEmpty(val)` returns a boolean for any numeric variable.  Or you could do `If Len(Trim(Cstr(val))) = 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following data. the last column has the formula for whichtoA

```
A   B   C   D   E
60% 40% 30% 30% ABC
30% 60% 30% 90% ABC
10% 20% 50%     ABC
    30% 50%     BC
        30%     C
        50% 60% CD
```

If you are using percentages you need to use something other than integer in your function since you're dealing with decimals.

```
Function whichtoa(w As Double, x As Double, y As Double, z As Double) As String
    Dim emptyCount As Integer
    Dim results As String

    ' Assume zero
    valueCount = 0
    ' Assume empty string
    results = ""

    If w <> 0 Then
        results = results & "A"
        valueCount = valueCount + 1
    End If

    If x <> 0 Then
        results = results & "B"
        valueCount = valueCount + 1
    End If

    If y <> 0 Then
        results = results & "C"
        valueCount = valueCount + 1
    End If

    ' This is the only time you need to check the condition of valueCount. If you want 3 maximum
    If (z <> 0) And (valueCount < 3) Then
        results = results & "D"
    End If

    whichtoa = results
End Function
```

Each condition is checked individually. The If block you have will only process the first match and then stop evaluating the block. Then, counting the number of positive values, or hits if you will, with `valueCount` we can stop processing if we get 3 hits. This only needs to be checked with `z` parameter in the event we have 3 hits already at that point. Build the results as a string and return it.

Comment: I was going for simple. I do enjoy another approach (No i'm not suggesting yours is complicated)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Needed something a bit different from this but this helped immeasurably and I got there in the end.

Answer (score 2):

Your conditional statement is chained: each `ElseIf` is only evaluated if the preceding `If` evaluates to `True`, so the function will only return a *single* string value (either A, B, C, or D but not a combination of multiple possible values, which would require stroing them all in a collection/dictionary/array/etc., and removing the ones that are empty values.

Compounded by implied type conversion (presumably you're passing range objects to this function, on a worksheet, which evaluate to their `.Value` which is "0" if the range is empty.

Another problem you may not have hit yet (if you're still working through the above) is that if the cell values contain percentages, by casting them as `Integer` in the function declaration, any values which round down to 0 will be evaluated as zero.

I suggest declaring the variables as Range objects, and then specifically check their `.Value` property. Store ALL cells and a key value ("A", "B", etc.) in a dictionary. Iterate the dictioanry and check the value for emptiness:

I also use this to return an error value if the dictionary contains 4 items, since you want a maximum of 3.

```
Function whichtoa(a As Range, b As Range, c As Range, d As Range)
Dim dict As Object
Dim itm As Variant

Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'Add each cell value to a dictionary, using unique letter as Key
dict("A") = a.Value
dict("B") = b.Value
dict("C") = c.Value
dict("D") = d.Value

'iterate the dictionary keys, removing empty values
For Each itm In dict.Keys()
    If IsEmpty(dict(itm)) Then dict.Remove (itm)
Next

If Not dict.Count = 4 Then 
    whichtoa = Join(dict.Keys(), ",")
Else:
    whichtoa = CVerr(2023)
End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks! Both of the answers helped a bunch! the percentage type is definitely confusing

Comment: well with the percentages, just remember that something like "6%" is **not** an integer, it's a decimal value of `0.06`, right?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure exactly what the return value is that you want (your example are inconsistent), but the following may point you in the right direction:

```
Public Function whichtoa(r as Range)

Dim arr, i

arr = Array("A", "B", "C", "D")

For i = 0 to 3
    If IsEmpty(r.Cells(1,i+1) Then
        arr(i) = "empty"
    End If
Next

whichtoa = arr(0) & "," & arr(1) & "," & arr(2) & "," & arr(3)

End Function
```

Comment: this only works if you can assume a contiguous range argument. `i` should probably be more strongly typed (as Integer/Long). You can use the `Join` function in your return statement :)

Comment: Like I said in my answer, I was only trying to point them in the right direction since the question was not clearly defined (for example it did not say whether non-contiguous ranges should be allowed for). And for the purposes here I didn't need to strongly type i, it was just a quick illustration of a possible approach. You give -1 for this????